# PowerShell Can't Execute File Without Extension

Tags: windows, powershell

I've been hunting around for a month, trying to figure this out.

**Windows 10 (1909)**

In `Windows PowerShell`, I am unable to simply type `docker`.  I **have** to type `docker.exe`.

In `Windows PowerShell (x86)`, `docker.exe` works fine.

`Get-ExecutionPolicy` is **Unrestricted** for both.

`$ENV:ExtPath` is `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL` for both.

`$ENV:Path` is the same for both:

```
C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\bin;;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\me\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

`$PSVersionTable` is the same for both:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.628
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.628
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

However, it ***seems*** to only affect `docker`.

Comment: Do you have a directory named DOCKER inside the current one when you try to run DOCKER?

Comment: Try adding docker to your System Environment variable, the PowerShell Environment variable or just create an alias for docker.exe in PowerShell. See details here: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2014/06/10/exe-alias-in-powershell.aspx

Comment: Run Process Monitor when you try running it, look how it checks the search path for the exe, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my goodness.  A big thanks to @HelpingHand for having me look at Process Monitor.

It took me a while to analyze what was happening.  It was getting stuck after looking in C:\windows\system32.  But something like OpenSSL wasn't getting stuck.

Turns out, there was an empty file in C:\windows\system32 named "docker".  I deleted that file, and it began to work.